# I am wrapping a string for a given width, but my code is not generating expected output

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, for-loop, jupyter-notebook

How can I find the error? Here is my code:

```
i=0
def wrap(string, max_width):        # function for providing string and max_width 
    for i in range(0,len(string)):   
        print(string[i:i+max_width])     
        i=i+max_width               # incrementing 'i' as per the max_width added by the user.
```

The above code o/p:

```
input : 'vivek'
output: 'vi'
        'iv'
        've'
        'ek'
        'k'
```

Correct O/P:

```
'vi'
've'
'k'
```

Comment: `i` is being overwritten in the loop on every iteration, that last line basically does nothing. Tip: `range(0, len(string), max_width)`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot increment the variable you use in a `for` loop like that, because they are overwritten in the next iteration. Either:

1. Use a while loop, or
2. Have `range` increment the variable by `max_width`: `range(0,len(string),max_width)`

Comment: Thankyou , What you have mentioned in your answer, I have found it  on the internet , just posted the question to get more info from the stackflow users group.

Comment: @VarishTripathi good! If the answer is what you were looking for, please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)